# shared storage per domain for the background and a popup in the chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, webrequest

I'm trying to create a plugin for the Chrome browser, where in the popup i print list of requests, which was made by the page on which is current active tab.

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "name": "Pixel Detector",
    "description": "A pixel detector for tracking codes.",
    "version": "1.0",

    "background": {
        "scripts": ["assets/js/background.js"]
    },

    "icons": {
        "32": "assets/img/icon32.png"
    },

    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "assets/img/icon32.png",
        "default_popup": "index.html"
    },

    "permissions": [
        "webRequest",
        "webRequestBlocking",
        "activeTab",
        "<all_urls>"
    ]
}
```

**background.js**

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
    function(details) {
        if(details.url.toLowerCase().indexOf("pixel.domain.com") > 0){
            var pixels = new Array();
            if(sessionStorage.getItem('pixels')){
                pixels = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('pixels'));
            }
            pixels.push(details.url);
            sessionStorage.setItem('pixels', JSON.stringify(pixels));
        }

    },
    {urls: ["<all_urls>"]}
);
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Pixel Detector</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/styles/styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <header class="header">
            <h1>Pixel Detector</h1>
        </header>
        <div class="content">
            <ul class="list">
                <table class="pixelsTable">
                    <thead class="pixelsTable__head">
                        <th>Name</th>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody class="pixelsTable__body">

                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I catch all requests without a problem, but I do not know how to pass them to index.html and main.js in the easiest way. What is really important to me, is that extension popup can be closed. Background.js should collect it to some array and pass it to the popup once it's open.

I have tried with global storage, worked okay, but i don't want to share it between all the tabs. It have to be local storage per each of domains.

I don't want to store anything once user open next website. I have tried also with `getBackgroundPage`, but it is shared by multiple domains and multiple tabs. I'm looking for something more primitive.

Comment: 1) You can also access the background page variables directly: chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().someGlobalVariable, 2) There's no such thing as "per-domain extension storage" so you'll have to use the URL/domain string as a key in a `Map` object or a standard object.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks :). As you suggested i made "global" map in the background page. I wonder now, how may I add listner to the something like onReload event. I have to clear key value, once user leaves page.

Comment: Assuming your map has tab id as the key, use chrome.tabs.onRemoved and chrome.tabs.onUpdated events.